# bug in ask question page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, asking-questions

The bug is that the ask question page does not include the toolbar on the editor, does not suggest similar posts, does not suggest tags, and does not react when you click answer your own question.

I am using Safari 6 in private browsing mode, and this bug is only present on some sites, not others. Meta works fine, but not Stack overflow, and I haven't looked at any other sites.

It is pretty hard to reproduce this bug, but I can show you a screenshot if necessary.

Edit: Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the JavaScript resources are being downloaded properly? Try [viewing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js) it. This is what [I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bkYho.png) when I disable JavaScript.